# Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged and modal view not covering the whole screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My app looks like this: **Tab bar** - **Nav Controller** - **Account VC** - **Login VC**(modal)

What I want to do is to redirect the user to a login screen if no session exist when hitting the account button (**Account VC**)

In **Account VC** I have setup this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if LocalStore.getToken() == nil {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("accountLoginSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

This will show the **Login VC** but the **Login VC** is set to be a modal VC but the tab bar still show up at the bottom which I dont want. And I also get this warning:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged
```

However if wrap the if-check inside:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

     })
```

The error will disappear but my modal VC (**Login VC**) still wont cover the whole screen making the tab bar visible

Comment: Move `performSegueWithIdentifier` to `viewDidAppear` it's detached because it's not on screen. What is the presentation style of the segue? If it's Current Context, change it to Full Screen.

Comment: @beyowulf That solved it thanks. But is viewDidAppear a good place to put it? I want to redirect to the login view right away without tyring to make any api calls. Also switching from "over current context" to "full screen" solved the fullscreen issue. But I have other modal VC's in my app set to over "current context" and it seems to work on certain pages somehow. And post your comment as a answer so that I can accept it :)